# Anaconda Navigator 2.4.2: Illegible small fonts on Windows 10

Tags: anaconda

I am following
[this](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/742)
thread to address the illegible small fonts on Anaconda Navigator.

I should add that I just migrated from an HP EliteBook 840 G6 to an HP
EliteBook 650 G9 because of a malfunctioning keyboard on the former.
Both have resolution 1920x1080.  On the 840 G6, the Anaconda version
was 2.4.0, while on the 650 G9, it is 2.4.2.  On the 840 G6, I saw
*normal* fonts, not the small fonts that I see now on the 650 G9.

As per the above thread, I tried `conda update anaconda-navigator`
from the Conda prompt, then restarted Anaconda Navigator.  No joy.

I also tried `conda update qt pyqt`, but got the error message:

```
PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3
  package name: qt
```

On the other hand, if I drop the `qt`, then `conda update pyqt` completes with `All requested packages already installed`.  However, the small fonts remained after relaunching
Anaconda Navigator.

I attempted the following at the Conda prompt:

```
set QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1
anaconda-navigator
```

However, `anaconda-navigator` is not recognized.  From the Start
Menu, the Anaconda Navigator shortcut *doesn't* contain the command
`anaconda-navigator`.  Rather, the command is complex:

```
C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\pythonw.exe ^
C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\cwp.py ^
C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3 ^
C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\pythonw.exe ^
C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py
```

At the Conda prompt, I tried setting `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1` as
per above and then running the complex command immediately above.
The small fonts remained when Anaconda Navigator launched.

In Anaconda Navigator, the `File->Preferences` panel contains a
checkbox for `Enable high DPI scaling`.  Toggling this and restarting
Anaconda Navigator had no effect.

What else can I do to troubleshoot this further?

**Afternote:** It looks like a [bug](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11837) reported in 2020.  It's odd that I see this problem with Anaconda 2.4.2, but not 2.4.0 (albeit on a different machine, though both are EliteBook laptops with the same resolution).  I also found that if I increase the [display scaling](https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/how_to_change_dpi_scaling_level_in_windows_10.html) from 100% to 125%, the text in Anaconda Navigator remains small, but if I use 150%, the Anaconda Navigator font sizes increase in a large quantum step.  Not ideal by any means, but I'll live with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi my solution is to uninstall anaconda and uninstall python (make sure to uninstall everyfile of both anaconda and python) then reinstall anaconda latest version. it worked for me. finally the font is good for me. I think its when the versions dont match thats when the font issue occurs and for gods sake when prompted do not update to latest version of anaconda when asked in opening first time. That is what created the small font issue for me.

Comment: Thanks!  I've speculatively marked it as the answer, as I won't have time to test it.  Too big a detour for me right now.